# implementing HighCharts-xrange in angular4

Tags: angular, highcharts

I am trying to use HighCharts of type xrange:

```
import { ChartModule } from 'angular2-highcharts';
import * as highcharts from 'highcharts';
import { HighchartsStatic } from '../../../../node_modules/angular2-highcharts/dist/HighchartsService';

export function highchartsFactory() {
  const hc = require('highcharts');
  const dd = require('highcharts/modules/xrange');
  dd(hc);

  return hc;
} 
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    /* case 1 */
    ChartModule 
    // in this case the code compiles but I get Error 17 in console

    /* case 2 */
    /* ChartModule.forRoot(require('highcharts'), require('highcharts/modules/xrange')) */
    // in this case the code doesn't compiles with the error:
    // "Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. 
    //  Calling function 'ChartModule', function calls are not supported."
  ],
  providers: [
    {
        provide: HighchartsStatic,
        useValue: highcharts,
        useFactory: highchartsFactory
    }
})
```

As shown in both cases I have a problem creating the chart. I have been told that the first case is the better approach and I would like to continue in this direction.

I saw many posts that use this approach and none of them mention this error.

Comment: check this implementation https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular4-highcharts-x-range?file=app/app.component.ts  using official highcharts npm

Comment: did you install highchart typings?

Comment: I get error of : `xrange_1.default is not a function
TypeError: xrange_1.default is not a function` @Deep 3015

Comment: Yes, I install highchart @ Chellappan

Comment: @AmichayAtias are you using using official highcharts npm and not angular2-highcharts

Comment: I install `"highcharts": "^6.1.1",` And `"angular2-highcharts": "^0.5.5",`. is this a problem?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use official highcharts npm package like in this [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular4-highcharts-x-range?file=app/app.component.ts), but you want to use angular2-highcharts.

Update you app-module with

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';

import { ChartModule } from 'angular2-highcharts';
import { HighchartsStatic } from 'angular2-highcharts/dist/HighchartsService';
import Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import Exporting from 'highcharts/modules/exporting';
import xrange from "highcharts/modules/xrange";
xrange(Highcharts);
Exporting(Highcharts);
export function highchartsFactory() {
  return Highcharts;
}
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule , ChartModule],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent ],
  providers: [
    { provide: HighchartsStatic, useFactory: highchartsFactory } // add as factory to your providers
  ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular4-x-range-highcharts?embed=1&file=app/app.component.ts) demo

Comment: When I import this: `import  Highcharts from 'highcharts';` is put error: `has no default export.` and if I do `import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';` is threw this error `TypeError: xrange_1.default is not a function TypeError: xrange_1.default is not a function`

Comment: you say I can use it without `angular2-highcharts.` if yes please show me how I tried in all possible ways and not success

Comment: I just created a new project like in the example that you sent me and I get this error when I hover on the import highcharts: `[ts]
Could not find a declaration file for module 'highcharts/modules/xrange'. 'c:/Users/User/my-app/node_modules/highcharts/modules/xrange.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/highcharts` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'highcharts';`. The project compiled but the chart doesn't build and I get this message in the console: `xrange_1.default is not a function` @Deep 3015

Comment: which example you are talking with angular2-highcharts or without

Comment: @ Deep 3015  without angular2-highcharts

Comment: And I try to install `npm install @types/highcharts --save` and I get error: `ts] Module '"c:/Users/User/my-app/node_modules/@types/highcharts/index"' has no default export.`

Comment: I am not able to make it work with angular 11. Is there any support guide ?